# Whole fraction numbers in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there an easy way to display whole rational numbers for example:

```
(average '(1 2 3 4)) ;returns 2 1/2
```

I would like it to return 5/2. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is DrRacket-specific behavior. It customizes the Racket print handler to print out certain values in "pretty" ways, some of which aren't even plain text. For example, DrRacket will print images as pictures in the REPL, and it will print syntax objects as *fully interactive* widgets that display source information along with the datum structure.

Racket reserves the `print` function to be customized, and it doesn't guarantee the output of such a function. If you want consistent output, use `write`, which will *always* produce plain text unless explicitly altered by the programmer.

```
(write (/ 5 2)) ; => 5/2
```

Note that in the REPL, `print` will use the same textual representation that `write` uses for exact, rational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numerator` and `denominator` to get the pieces you want. Something like:

```
(let* ((avg (average '(1 2 3 4)))
       (num (numerator avg))
       (den (denominator avg)))
   (printf "~a/~a~n" num den)))
```